# Derivative long equation in matlab, then calculation the result

Tags: matlab, derivative

I have a example like this:
I have a velocity of one element===derivative it====> the acceleration of element.
The velocity is calculate from many equation, like this:

```
    syms m w k E mI c w t L z;
E=2.7*10^10;
L=21;
mI=0.001332;
z=5;
m=500;
k=1*10^7;
c=30000;
w=300;
t=1;
a=((((m*w^2-k)/(E*mI))^2+(c*w/(E*mI))^2)^(1/8));
b=(atan(-c*w/(m*w^2-k))/4+pi/4);
syms cosi(w);
cosi=a*exp(t*b);
delta=2*(1-cosh(cosi*L)*cos(cosi*L));
syms v(w);
v=((sin(cosi*L)-sinh(cosi*L))*(cosh(cosi*z)+cos(cosi*z))+(cosh(cosi*L)...
    -cos(cosi*L))*(sinh(cosi*z)+sin(cosi*z)))...
    /(E*mI*cosi^3*delta);

f=jacobian(v,w);
```

With m,k,E,mI,c are constant, w is independent variable.
1.Now I want to calculate the derivative of v
2.Now I want to compile these code into Net assembly to call it by c# program. How can I fix it.

```
function [resultv,resultf]=Untitled4(m1, w1, k1, E1, mI1, c1, t1, L1, z1)
syms m w k E mI c w t L z cosi(w)
a=((((m*w^2-k)/(E*mI))^2+(c*w/(E*mI))^2)^(1/8));
b=(atan(-c*w/(m*w^2-k))/4+pi/4);
cosi=a*exp(t*b);
delta=2*(1-cosh(cosi*L)*cos(cosi*L));
v=((sin(cosi*L)-sinh(cosi*L))*(cosh(cosi*z)+cos(cosi*z))+(cosh(cosi*L)...
    -cos(cosi*L))*(sinh(cosi*z)+sin(cosi*z)))...
    /(E*mI*cosi^3*delta);

f=jacobian(v,w);

E=E1;
L=L1;
mI=mI1;
z=z1;
m=m1;
k=k1;
c=c1;
w=w1;
t=t1;
resultv=double(subs(v));
resultf = double(subs(f));
end
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jacobian`. Let's say you want to derive wrt `w`

```
syms m w k E mI c w t L z 

a=((((m*w^2-k)/(E*mI))^2+(c*w/(E*mI))^2)^(1/8));
b=(atan(-c*w/(m*w^2-k))/4+pi/4);
cosi=(a*exp(t*b));
delta=2*(1-cosh(cosi*L)*cos(cosi*L));
v=((sin(cosi*L)-sinh(cosi*L))*(cosh(cosi*z)+cos(cosi*z))+(cosh(cosi*L)...
    -cos(cosi*L))*(sinh(cosi*z)+sin(cosi*z)))...
    /(E*mI*cosi^3*delta);

jacobian(v,w)
```

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION HAS BEEN UPDATED**

```
syms m w k E mI c w t L z cosi(w)
a=((((m*w^2-k)/(E*mI))^2+(c*w/(E*mI))^2)^(1/8));
b=(atan(-c*w/(m*w^2-k))/4+pi/4);
cosi=a*exp(t*b);
delta=2*(1-cosh(cosi*L)*cos(cosi*L));
v=((sin(cosi*L)-sinh(cosi*L))*(cosh(cosi*z)+cos(cosi*z))+(cosh(cosi*L)...
    -cos(cosi*L))*(sinh(cosi*z)+sin(cosi*z)))...
    /(E*mI*cosi^3*delta);

f=jacobian(v,w);

E=2.7*10^10;
L=21;
mI=0.001332;
z=5;
m=500;
k=1*10^7;
c=30000;
w=300;
t=1;

results = double(subs(f))
```

Comment: If I put these number in the code, I can't get the right result
E=2.7*10^10;
L=21;
mI=0.001332;
z=5;
m=500;
k=1*10^7;
c=30000;
w=300;
Could you please to help me more

Comment: There is no way Matlab is wrong. What about `t`? Do you have to derive wrt to `t`? Because I did wrt to `w`. And what is its value when you put it in the result?

Comment: i'm sorry. I'm using a wrong word. When I input these number. the matlat don't give the resul. When I check in the workspace colum. the f value is 1x1 syms. I derive v to f. Please see the code i Update in the first comment. I need a result of v, and f after I derive. Thank for your help.

Comment: You are putting the numerical value before deriving. It's like you derive `y = x^2` in `x = 1` but you do that after inserting `x = 1`. This is basic math.

Comment: Dear Mr @Simon.
Now I want to compile these  code into Net assembly to call by C# program. How can I fix it to compile. Please help me to fix it in the update question. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm sorry but I have never done it. You should open a new question for it.

Comment: can you check the last code is right or wrong. I put these in the matlab, it can't run. (chang E1,mI1... by number). Thank you very much

Comment: I can run it and seems to works. However, I suggest you to open a new question, not to modify this one, to ask for the C# stuff. In thast way, it will get more views.